# I want create this Sliding UIVies in xcode using swift, what sholud i used ? an collecntionView or TableView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview, collectionview

i want to create an exact screen in my ios application with xcode & swift im not able to create it, what shall i used? an *collectionView* or *ScroolView*?

> import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{


@IBOutlet weak var newCollectionView: UICollectionView!






override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    newCollectionView.delegate = self
    newCollectionView.dataSource = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use UIScrollView in horizontal. And try to round coordinations of subviews and after dragging use `let p  = CGPoint(x: yourX, y: 0);
        scrollView.setContentOffset(p, animated: true)`. Where `yourX = scrollItems[i].width * i`;

Comment: can you please describe this  thing in details please ?

Comment: I have answered below. I think you can add your dots on top of `ViewController` and change it in `methodAnimation`.

Comment: Ha e you solved your problem?

Comment: Can you please share me your source code to anujbidkar8@gmail.com or share github link thank you

Comment: Here is a link: https://github.com/Agisight/scroller.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my class. It works completely. Also i added an image of storyboard. Link to my github project : https://github.com/Agisight/scroller.git

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var scroll: UIScrollView!

    @IBOutlet var btns: [UIView]!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scroll.delegate = self
    }
    func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
        methodAnimation()
    }

    func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        methodAnimation()
    }

    func methodAnimation() {
        if btns.count == 0 {return}

        var i = 0
        // i – calculate it, it is your visible/desirable view.
        // here is variant of code
        let dragOffset = view.frame.width * 0.5 // callibrate it for you
        let offX = scroll.contentOffset.x
        i = Int(offX + dragOffset) / Int(view.frame.width)

        i = max(0, min(i, btns.count - 1))
        let yourX = btns[i].frame.width * CGFloat(i) // ()
        let p = CGPoint(x: yourX, y: 0);
        scroll.setContentOffset(p, animated: true)
    }
}
```

[image: My UIViewController with scroll]